# How to enter pcap filter in Wireshark 1.8?

Tags: networking, gui, wireshark, pcap

Previously in capture options window there was a very handy input field for pcap filter expression. But in 1.8.* this window looks different:[image: Capture options window, image taken from official user guide]
So, how to set pcap filter expression before starting capture in wireshark >= 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on the interface you want to capture to edit the capture filter.

Comment: oh... this is incredibly intuitive© and user-friendly®...